# JavaScript function not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I have a function in a separate .js file called `jQuery.loadjson.js`. That being called from my HTML page with the syntax `$('#data').loadJSON(data);`

`#data` is a div and `data` is a JSON object. Now, when I debug that in Firebug, it just does not go to the definition.

Comment: Look at your question. Do you believe anyone in the world could help you, based only on the information you've given us?

Comment: what exactly is in that code (`loadJSON()`)? giving us only scarce info won't solve anything.

Comment: There is no excuse for not using a debugger. Trace through it.

Comment: Well, LoadJson is a .js file that will "Read the incoming Json object and MAP or produce HTMl document to display the data."

Comment: I am calling it from my htm page and pass some JSOn data inside it, but as I said instean of debugger taking me to JQuery.JSON.js's code where I did put some break points it loads "function onclick(event) {
callLoadJson();
}"

Comment: You have either A) written the jquery.fn.yourmethod wrong. B) added the reference of your script before the jquery script. C) forgotten to add a reference to your script.

Comment: @Californicated then put all the related code in the question to clarify

Comment: Hi Guys, yes it was a syntax error in my .Js and instead of highlighting the error, FireBug would actually take me it some cryptic eventhandler. Now it is fine. Thank you so much for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firebug, enable 'use strict warnings' from the drop down on the console tab, then load the page again and see what you get.

If it's still not obvious what's wrong, post the last entries from the console log here. Make sure it's set to 'show all' so you don't miss anything!

If it gets to that line but never goes to the definition, my guess would be that the data variable is undefined, or that loadJSON() is not being attached to that object.

Comment: sometimes, errors in jQuery don't appear in the console. they fail silently, especially those AJAX calls.

Comment: True, but worth a shot. Installing FireQuery can help sometimes: http://firequery.binaryage.com/

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too but that did not help :((

Comment: In which case, we will need to see some more code :)